# How can I pass the name of the file that was changed in launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd

I am trying to watch a directory for changes via launchd. My plist
file looks like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/Users/myname/bin/boink</string>
  <string>path modified</string>
</array>
```

All this works OK, but I would like to pass the name of the file that
was changed as an argument to the script /Users/myname/bin/boink

Is that possible? the man page isn't very helpful, nor did googling help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to monitor the file system for changes yourself.  Check out the File System Events Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH1-SW1

Comment: @simone: Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no. `launchd(8)` uses Kqueue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) to receive this kind of notification. Unfortunately `kqueue(2)` does not return *which* item has triggered the event.

You may want to use the `launchd(8)` key `QueueDirectories` instead. It works essentially the same way `WatchPaths` works, but it assumes that the processing agent/daemon is moving the processed items from the directory being monitored to another one. So whenever an event is triggered your job can process *every* file in the monitored directory. Just make sure you move them after processing.